# Truffle exec ETIMEDOUT

Tags: truffle, rinkeby

I'm running a batch script that would create up to hundreds of concurrent transactions and wait for their completion

```
truffle exec scripts/....js --network rinkeby ...
```

everything works but after certain amount of time when the script is still running just fine, the process is terminated with error message ETIMEDOUT

no stack trace, no further explanation. I'm using Truffle v5.0.9, thought there is some sort of timeout option for truffle exec but can't find any, did not find relevant resources either.

I'm confident this is not an issue in my code as the script catches all errors and report them with callback(errs).
any ideas?

Comment: Was this resolved? I may be having a similar issue, and I think it is related to infura.

Comment: I never figured out root cause, but after trial and error found it to be related to network

Comment: Please check my answer here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/98322/bsc-testnet-truffle-migrate-etimedout