# BSC Testnet: Truffle Migrate ETIMEDOUT

Tags: blockchain, binance

I need to deploy my smart contract to BSC Testnet

I always got this :

```
Error: PollingBlockTracker - encountered an error while attempting to update latest block:
Error: ETIMEDOUT
I tried to change the RPC specified here https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/developer/rpc.html#rate-limit
```

All of them, yet still the same.

One thing is, I tried to deploy it to ropsten instead just for fun. And it is success. Is there any problem with BSC Testnet RPC nowadays ?

Here is my snip for truffle-config.js

```
        testnet: {
            provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s2.binance.org:8545`),
            network_id: 97, // 3 for ropsten, 97 for bsc test
            confirmations: 2,
            timeoutBlocks: 2000,
            skipDryRun: true,
            networkCheckTimeout: 1000000
        },
```

I searched, some people use websocket (wss), some change the RPC Url, some add the networkCheckTimeout. I tried all of them (except wss, since I don't see it is provided by BSC Testnet). But nothing work.

Any suggestion ? Thank you

Answer (score 11):

If you compile a lot of files, truffle ask for the lastest block.
Since BSC testnet limits the amount of request you can make, it hangs
and then you get a timeout.
I solved this issue just compiling my code first and for deploy, using --compile-none.

```
truffle deploy --network testnet --reset --compile-none
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I might try it when there is another chance. For now, I had abandoned truffle and use remix instead. No problem at all with remix and somehow, it is also faster. So, I dont think I'll be back to use truffle for a while.

Comment: Seriously truffle got an issue. Correct that remix will work without an issue but not truffle.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that BSC produces blocks so quickly that it exceeds the default number of blocks Truffle is configured to wait for. You can solve this by adding the `networkCheckTimeout` and `timeoutBlocks` fields in your network config:

```json
bsc: {
  networkCheckTimeout: 1000000,
  timeoutBlocks: 200
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I recreated the project, but this time I downloaded `npm install @truffle/hdwallet-provider` before `truffle init`.

Also make sure your bscTestnet in `networks` section of truffle-config.js file looks like this:

```
    bscTestnet: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(
        privateKeys,
        'https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545/'
      ),
      network_id: 97,
      skipDryRun: true
    }
```